# AngularJS templates not showing on page but are there when page is inspected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router

I am new to using Angular and Rails and have gotten stuck when I imported my Angular project into a Rails project and split the templates into individual files. Now the nav and footer partials show, but the templates will not load on the page. I am getting this error in the browser console:

"Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'galleryApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument"

When I inspect the page the template is there. Let me know if I can provide any more information to help. Thanks in advance for the help!

application.html.erb

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Gallery</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6e04e9b3c4.js"></script>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="galleryApp">

    <div ng-include="'nav/_nav.html'"></div>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
    <div ng-include="'footer/_footer.html'"></div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('galleryApp', ['ui.router', 'templates']);

app.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('teleport', {
        url: '/teleport',
        templateUrl: 'teleport/_teleport.html',
        controller: 'CoverImageCtrl'
      });
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('teleport');
}]);
```

teleport.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/teleport.html">

  <div id="teleport-gallery" class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="teleport-images" ng-repeat="myCoverImage in myCoverImages" ng-mouseover="style={'height':'410px','width':'410px'}" ng-mouseleave="style={'height':'400px','width':'400px'}">
        <a href="#/galleries/{{$index}}"><img class ="teleport-images" ng-style="style"  ng-hide="changeImage" ng-src="{{getCoverImagePath(myCoverImage.image)}}" alt="super awesome picture" /></a>
        <h2 class="teleport-titles">{{myCoverImage.title}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

coverImageCtrl.js

```
var app = angular.module('galleryApp');

app.controller('CoverImageCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  function($scope){
    $scope.myCoverImages = [
      {image: "san_francisco/Corgi.png", title: "San Diego"},
      {image: "baja/secret-hideaway.png", title: "Chicago"},
      {image: "new_orleans/llama.jpg", title: "New Orleans"},
      {image: "chicago/mex.jpg", title: "San Francisco"},
      {image: "los_angeles/surfing-1400X600.jpg", title: "Los Angeles"},
      {image: "san_diego/rainbow_shave_ice_800.jpg", title: "Baja Nor"}
    ];

    $scope.getCoverImagePath = function(coverImageName) {
      return  "../../images/galleries/" + coverImageName;
    };

}]);
```

application.js

```
// = require angular
// = require angular-rails-templates
// = require angular-ui-router
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I needed to remove the <script type="text/ng-template" id="/teleport.html"> tag around my template when I moved it from being an inline template in application.html.erb to its own partial file. I am still getting the same error in my console, but everything seems to be working fine. Any ideas on why I am getting this error? Thanks.

"angular.self-7f8df3e….js?body=1:69 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'galleryApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.(…)"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your angular files and your app.js, aren't you?

```
<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check my comment for what ended up working for me. Thanks!